# Base64 Word document - image not displayed

Tags: javascript, ms-word

I receive a `WordProcessingDocument` as base64 from my web service.

I am trying now to donwload it in the client side. (HTML/JS)

**Javascript**

```
var file = base64String;
var url = 'data:application/msword;base64,' + file;
window.location.href = url;
```

The word is actually downloading and evertyhing is going well except for one thing. 
I got 2 image, one from a the template word and an other one that I programmaticaly add. 
The second one is not displayed.

```
This image cannot currently be displayed
```

It is maybe link to this "error" that appears when I download the word

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/msword:
```

Comment: Output your template on the server side and check if the image is there - this seems to be more of a problem with the word document creation (on the server side).

Comment: Indeed, I am trying to create a new image with a null data... my bad. Thx for the help